# Draw lines between matched parts of two sequences

Tags: matlab, plot, line, time-series, octave

I have two different sequences: `seq1` and `seq2`.

```
seq1 = {1,2,3,4}; 
seq2 = {3,4,6,7,8}; 
matchedIndexes ={{4,5},{4,4},{4,3},{4,2},{3,1},{2,1},{1,1}};
```

I want to draw `seq1` and `seq2` along with lines between matched parts using matlab in the same plot.

I have tried the following,

```
plot(seq1);
hold on;
plot(seq2);
//How to draw lines between matched parts?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want (in Matlab):

```
seq1 = {1,2,3,4}; 
seq2 = {3,4,6,7,8}; 
matchedIndexes ={{4,5},{4,4},{4,3},{4,2},{3,1},{2,1},{1,1}};

seq1 = cell2mat(seq1); %// convert to vector
seq2 = cell2mat(seq2); %// convert to vector
plot(seq1,1,'ro')
hold on
plot(seq2,2,'ro')
for k = 1:numel(matchedIndexes)
    plot([seq1(matchedIndexes{k}{1}) seq2(matchedIndexes{k}{2})], [1 2])
end
axis([min([seq1 seq2])-1 max([seq1 seq2])+1 0.5 2.5])
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mean: `plot([matchedIndexes{k}{1} matchedIndexes{k}{2}], [seq1(matchedIndexes{k}{1}) seq2(matchedIndexes{k}{2})])` in the `for` loop. The rest is perfect.

Comment: @celebisait Thanks for your comment, but I don't get it. If you try it replacing that line (and removing the final `axis` line), it gives a strange picture, where lines and circles don't match

Comment: Added another answer for putting the plot.

Comment: @celebisait Oh, I see: you are also changing the first `plot` lines as well. Now it makes sense. Well, it's just another interpretation of how to plot the sequences (and their connecting lines). +1

Answer (score 3):

Using @Luis Mendo's code:

```
seq1 = {1,2,3,4}; 
seq2 = {3,4,6,7,8}; 
matchedIndexes ={{4,5},{4,4},{4,3},{4,2},{3,1},{2,1},{1,1}};

seq1 = cell2mat(seq1); %// convert to vector
seq2 = cell2mat(seq2); %// convert to vector
plot(seq1)
hold on
plot(seq2)

for k = 1:numel(matchedIndexes)
    plot([matchedIndexes{k}{1} matchedIndexes{k}{2}], [seq1(matchedIndexes{k}{1}) seq2(matchedIndexes{k}{2})], 'r')
end
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is what I want to draw.